# iOS: Passing objects into a ASIHTTPRequest Block?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, reference, asihttprequest, block

I am trying to create a function which uses ASIHTTPRequest, and return an instance of a MyPhotoSource class as follows..

```
- (MyPhotoSource *) photoSourceForURL:(NSURL *)url {

    MyPhotoSource *source;

    __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setCompletionBlock:^{

    .....

    source = [[MyPhotoSource alloc] initWithPhotos:photoArray];

    }];

    [request startAsynchronous];

    return source;

}
```

When I build the project, it gives me *Assignment of a read-only variable 'source'* error message.

I tried the following modification, however the project crashes at run-time.

```
__block MyPhotoSource *source;
```

Comment: You don't need `__block` on `ASIHTTPRequest`. The crash might be coming from the fact that `return source;` will always return `nil` because the object is not initialized until inside the block. Which happens asynchronously on another thread. So you might be running into issues later on in the app trying to use the returned object because it's `nil` or I'm not sure how gracefully this object will be updated once the block runs...

Comment: You're right. I changed it to a synchronous request and it worked well. So passing objects safely to asynchonous request blocks is impossible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are hoping for in this code but when you use an async callback you usually update a persistent object like an ivar. So if you only have one or a few `MyPhotoSource` objects make them ivars, return nothing from this function, then fill them in the block an call some sort of update function or notification.